# C# Use MKL library in mono

Tags: c#, mono, intel-mkl, intel-ipp

I have C# Console project that develop in visual studio on Windows with .net framework 4.6. In my project use MKL and IPP library. In Windows my project run correctly. I migrate to CentOS 7 and want run my project in this OS. I have several problem that resolved. Now my project build successful and run correct until now use MKL library. In first use of MKL get `System.DllNotFoundException" mkl_rt.dll` error. but all MKL dll (include of mkl_rt.dll) exist beside of .exe file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download MKL for linux from https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl/choose-download

after install this `.so` file exist. you can find `libmkl_rt.so` and copy it beside your .exe file or add this to ldconfig.

Answer (score 0):

One note - Libmkl_rt.so enables you to select the interface and threading library for Intel MKL at run time. By default, libmkl_tr.so is linking with intel threading run time – libiomp5. Therefore in your cases, you need to add this shared object into your system paths as well. See more details follow mkl developer user guide “[Using the Single Dynamic Libraries](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-linux-developer-guide-using-the-single-dynamic-library)”